# How to obtain $y$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, self-learning

[image]

The question was written with dark-blue pen. And I tried to solve this question. I obtained $x$ as it is below.  But I cannot obtain $y$  Please show me how to do this.

By the way, $\gamma (t)$ may not be clearly readable. So, I wrote again.

$$\gamma (t)=( \cos ^2 (t)-1/2, \sin(t)\cos (t), \sin (t))$$

Thanks for helping.

-sorry for not writing with MathJax. -

Comment: What does it mean to substruct an equation?

Comment: That's, $x^2+y^2-[(x+1/2)^2+y^2+z^2]=1/4-1$ @dfeuer

Comment: Ah, subtract. The structure of the parameterization suggests to me that the double angle formulas for sine and cosine may help simplify things.

Comment: I didnt see, I wrote Wrong. Sorry:( @dfeuer

Comment: Hmm, but I dont understand enough what you said. @dfeuer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your work,
$$x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow y^2=\frac{1}{4}-x^2,$$
and
$$x=\cos^2 t -\frac{1}{2}.$$

Substituting the latter into the former produces
\begin{align*}
y^2 &=\frac{1}{4}-x^2 \\
&=\frac{1}{4}-\left( \cos^2 t - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \\
&=\frac{1}{4}-\left( \cos^4 t - \cos^2 t + \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
&=\cos^2 t - \cos^4 t \\
&=\cos^2 t\left( 1-\cos^2 t \right) \\
&=\cos^2 t \sin^2 t \\
\Rightarrow y &= \sin t \cos t,
\end{align*}
as was your intention.

Comment: Ahhh It is so easy, but I didnt notice this. :( thank you so much:)

Comment: Forest through the trees. :)

Comment: Nope. Everything is okay;))

Comment: Ahaha you're so clever:))

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To get a clearer picture, multiply $\gamma$ by $2$. Then use the double angle formulas.

For reference, the double angle identities are as follows:

1. $\sin (2x)=2\sin x \cos x$
2. $\cos(2x)=\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = 2\cos^2 x - 1 = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$.

Comment: Doesnt there exist a way like my first solution? I dont know the way you said.

Comment: @B11b, do you know the double angle identities? They're pretty much the key to finishing your solution, as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, I never have heart it. My diffrential geometry instructor didnt state this.

Comment: @B11b, I wrote them up in my answer.

Comment: Yeup I know this. Sorry, I dont know its name in English, so I didnt understand. Well, how to use these to get $y$?

Comment: @B11b, first use them to change your $x$ to a different form.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping:)